# Using a DropDown value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I need to send the value of the selected option in a `<select>` element in some jquery to send to my php file.

Unfortunately, I keep getting an undefined value for it...

```
<select name="query" id="query">
    <option value="join-us">Join Us</option>
    <option value="work-with-us">Work with us</option>
    <option value="about-pf">About Planet Fitness</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

var query = $('#query option:selected').text();

console.log('query = ' + query);
```

The console.log returns

> query = undefined

I've tried using `$('#query').val();` and `$('#query').text();`

I don't know what else to do here.

It seems to me that the `:selected` psuedoclass requires the option to appear as follows in the markup.

```
<option value="bla" selected="selected">bla</option>
```

Clearly, I'm missing these but changing the selection in the dropdown isn't changing this and I don't think there'd be any sense to adding it into the markup myself...

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `$('#query').val()` should work fine.

Comment: I believe that's what I started with though @ŁukaszW.pl

Comment: Where is your script? Is it inside a ready?

Comment: Script is on a .click() because I only need it to run when the data is submitted

Comment: Still, are you defining the click handler after the DOM knows about the select? Try `console.log($('#query'));`

Comment: I have the click at the bottom of the page (right before `</body>` but the jquery where this script is, is being referenced in the `<head>`

Comment: That is the issue, add the jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @ATOzTOA no need for a document.ready function if the script block is already at the end right before the closing body tag

Comment: @Ortund works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/yJNqm/

Comment: Can you shared your code, the click and the jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#query option').filter(':selected').val();
```

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wE8Xe/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `.val()`

```
$('#query').change(function () {
    var query = $(this).val();
    $('#result').html('query = ' + query);
});
```

You should be calling `$('#query').val()` the moment you're going to submit.

http://jsfiddle.net/33GSy/1/

Comment: Yes, but I gave him a jsfiddle to see it working. I'll edit to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go... using jQuery 1.8.3...

---

***Experiment 1*** : [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3E6jJ/)

**Code**

```
<select name="query" id="query">
    <option value="join-us">Join Us</option>
    <option value="work-with-us">Work with us</option>
    <option value="about-pf">About Planet Fitness</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<script>
    var query1 = $('#query option:selected').text();
    var query2 = $('#query').val();
    var query3 = $('#query').text();

    alert('query1 = ' + query1 + '\nquery2 = ' + query2 + '\nquery3 = ' + query3);
    console.log('query1 = ' + query1 + '\nquery2 = ' + query2 + '\nquery3 = ' + query3);
</script>
```

**Output**

Chrome:

```
query1 = Join Us
query2 = join-us
query3 = 
    Join Us
    Work with us
    About Planet Fitness
    Other
```

IE:

```
query1 = Join Us
query2 = join-us
query3 = Join Us Work with us About Planet Fitness Other
```

Firefox:

```
query1 = Join Us
query2 = join-us
query3 = 
    Join Us
    Work with us
    About Planet Fitness
    Other
```

---

***Experiment 2*** : [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3MjPc/)

**Code**

```
    <script>
        function getMyValue() {
            var query1 = $('#query option:selected').text();
            var query2 = $('#query').val();
            var query3 = $('#query').text();

            alert('query1 = ' + query1 + '\nquery2 = ' + query2 + '\nquery3 = ' + query3);
            console.log('query1 = ' + query1 + '\nquery2 = ' + query2 + '\nquery3 = ' + query3);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select name="query" id="query">
        <option value="join-us">Join Us</option>
        <option value="work-with-us">Work with us</option>
        <option value="about-pf">About Planet Fitness</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="getMyValue();">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

**Output** (Clicking the button after choosing "Work with us"

Chrome:

```
query1 = Work with us
query2 = work-with-us
query3 = 
    Join Us
    Work with us
    About Planet Fitness
    Other
```

IE:

```
query1 = Work with us
query2 = work-with-us
query3 = Join Us Work with us About Planet Fitness Other
```

Firefox:

```
query1 = Work with us
query2 = work-with-us
query3 = 
    Join Us
    Work with us
    About Planet Fitness
    Other
```

---

**Inference**

Your code works fine, should be something wrong with the way you are invoking it, try putting alerts all over the place...

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling `$('#query option:selected').text();`?

This works fine for me:

```
$('#query').change(function() {
    var query = $('#query option:selected').text();

    console.log('query = ' + query);
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6excJ/).

**Edit:** What's with the downvote? The example I provided works fine in Chrome and IE.

Here is an updated version showing the exact same thing with a button click event: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6excJ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine.

```
var query = $('#query option:selected').text();
console.log('query = ' + query);
```

Please see jsFiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/FJCSu/3/